# Доступ в таблицу SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

`

```
public void DataBaze()
        {
            using (Test_Baza_ASP_Entities baza = new Test_Baza_ASP_Entities())
            {
                Test_Table dataContact = new Test_Table()
                {
                    Index_name = name,

                };
                baza.Test_Tables.Add(dataContact);
                baza.SaveChanges();
            }
        }`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ASP.NETщики и просто C# юзеры и спецы по базам данных) Помогите найти проблему. Выполняю простое учебное задание по ASP.NET. Цель — с текстбоксов считать данные и записать в базу данных использую DetailsView. Все просто, тем более когда уже прошел Entity и есть свое приложение и рабочая база(Avrbaza) с таблицей куда я записываю данные по методу создание модели EF.

Сначала решил просто кодбихайдом по старинке через создание модели без DetailsView записать данные. Для своего задания создаю новую базу(test_asp_baza) как и создавал старую, создаю таблицу как и создавал старую. Создаю подключение так же. Код четкий, простой и красивый как в рабочем моем приложение. Результат-ошибка на моменте .SaveChanges()

Идем далее. Делаю по методу DetailsView и прям в конструкторе создаю подключение где у меня у таблице необходимые пункты(INSERT, UPDATE DELETE) выбрать не могу

Далее еще интереснее. Беру старую рабочею базу через «не хочу» (она рабочая и трогать ее не хочется) и там создаю таблицу. Результат тот же — не хочет записывать и давать доступ.

И далее вообще самое главное. Решил рискнуть и записать тестовые данные в рабочею таблицу с рабочей базы(Avrbaza). И тут все работает по обоим методам. DetailsView необходимые пункты можно выбрать EF тоже через модель без проблем записывает.

Вопрос: Как я так создал ту таблицу, что я могу там все изменять, а в новое нет, даже если она создается в рабочей базе данных? Проверял все свойства таблице — все идентично. СУБД Microsoft SQL Server. Базу создаю в SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: Все нужные скрины и проблемный код вставляйте сюда, ссылки куда то там навряд ли кто то будет смотреть.

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо

Comment: Судя по всему, у вас Database First. Как переключаетесь между базами? просто заменой connection string в таблице? или обновлением модели в дизайнере? Если второе - то, судя по всему, у вас в "новой" базе нет PrimaryKey в проблемной таблице, и EF просто не может сгенерировать sql для вставки (часть про "должны быть выбраны все поля основного ключа) - т.к. без primary key непонятно, как именно отличать записи друг от друга

Comment: У вас ведь проблема в коде, так? Как вы предполагаете вам помогут с кодом, если кода в вопросе нет? Ваши словесные описания кода не имеют смысла, так как если бы вы точно знали, что делаете, то вопросов бы не было. А значит вы что то где то не понимаете, а значит и объяснение ваше - это грубое описание неверной интерпретации проблемного кода.. Потому код в студию

Comment: PashaPash  Нет, с PrimaryKey о там и там объявлен при создание таблицы одинаково (автоматом генерирует). С таким я уже сталкивался и точно знаю как с этим бороться, там что дело не в ключах

Comment: tym32167 та проблема не в коде..тут кода то меньше чем 2+2. Всю остальную модель генерит автоматом EF. Мне кажется тут проблема где-то в свойствах доступа которые стоят где-то по умолчанию... загрузил код выше

Comment: tym32167 я єтот код как и под рабочею таблицу и новую  таблицу подставляю...в рабочей все работает, в новой нет.

Comment: @FX_Sektor ок. давайте еще раз - как вы переключаетесь между базами? как вы "поставляете под рабочею табицу"? просто заменой connection string в таблице? или обновлением модели в дизайнере? Не уверен что означает "автоматом генерирует", но SQL Server не генерирует автоматом Primary Key. Зайдите в новую базу в management studio и убедитесь, что вы там проставили PK. И что колонка с PK выбрана в дизайнере. Сейчас, судя по скрину, у вас или EF не нашел колонки с PK на таблице в базе (потому что ее там нет!), или на самом деле это в базе не таблица в базе, а View.

Comment: PashaPash обновлением модели ....я не переключаюсь между базами..а просто удаляю модель и создаю новую...сюда просто подставляю новые название классов для экземпляра базы и таблицы. Модель все находит отлично. Так как если шагать F11 но данные записываются да и в моделе атоматом генерирует свойства доступа к колонкам. Даже если снести полностью приложение и создать новую базу то все равно то же самое. В новой базе и таблице захожу и автоматом ставлю  PK еще при создание. Да SQL Server не генерирует автоматом, но я это еще при создание указываю в первой колонке PK

Comment: PashaPash )))) ты был прав. Вот как оно решилось: Я зашел через VS в конструктор рабочей и не рабочей таблицы и увидел отличие)) вообще странно, автоматом он генерирует эту штуку если изначально в самом SQL MS указать Identity Specification (is Idetity) 1,1. Но когда я создал подключение и зашел через конструктор в таблицу и увидел что там нет ключа автоматом и не хватает строки внизу как в рабочей таблице "CONSTRAINT [AK_Table_Test_Column] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([key] ASC)" и все пашет)) спс .... PS все равно странно, он автоматом должен это указать.

Comment: PashaPash оставь ответ что б я клацнул как решенный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как оно решилось: Я зашел через VS в конструктор рабочей и не рабочей таблицы и увидел отличие)) вообще странно, автоматом он генерирует эту штуку если изначально в самом SQL MS указать Identity Specification (is Idetity) 1,1. Но когда я создал подключение и зашел через конструктор в таблицу и увидел что там нет ключа автоматом и не хватает строки внизу как в рабочей таблице "CONSTRAINT [AK_Table_Test_Column] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([key] ASC)" и все пашет)) спс .... PS все равно странно, он автоматом должен это указать.